# Is there any "modulo" equivalent representation for XNOR?

Tags: operators

I don't know if this is the right home for this question but since this kind of explanation is used in programming I am posting it here. If I am wrong, please respond in this post and will transfer the question to another home.

So after studying digital logic I came to know that each of the logic gates have their equivalent in programming, like AND, OR and NOT have their separate operators. And for XOR I have been told that it is equivalent to **modulo 2** of the number of inputs in an actual logic gate. But what about XNOR? Is there any representation of this type for XNOR? And is that explanation generalized? Like 'modulo 2' is generalized for 3-4 any n number of inputs. Does this apply for XNOR as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear here, `xor` is actually equivalent to modulo 2 of the number of ***true*** inputs. Your original statement (without the word "true") could be misread as including both true and false inputs.

In any case, since `xnor` is simply the complement of `xor`, it's a relatively simple matter to invert the outgoing value by injecting one extra truth value. In pseudo-code, that would be:

```py
def xor(inputs):
    value = sum(inputs) modulo 2

def xnor(inputs):
    value = (sum(inputs) + 1) modulo 2
```